# $_SESSION never getting set

Tags: php, unit-testing, session, authentication

I'm working on an assignment on a PHP course, and I'm stucked at the last part of it.

The assignment is to create a simple login form and use a session as well as hardcoded usernames and passwords (i.e. no db).

What I have problems with is the class that handles the login, and sessions especially. There's a lot of code and I didn't know what I could remove and therefore I've put it on Pastebin instead, hope that's alright.

Thing is that the unit tests that's built into the class passes except for nr. 4, the one that's checking that the user is logged in. The problem seems to be that $_SESSION[$this->loginSession] doesn't get set, and this is what I need help with.

The variable $loginSession is declared in the beginning of the class, and should be set to "isLoggedIn" when a user types a correct username and password, but that doesn't happen (no error message).

My class is:

```
<?php

class LoginHandler {

        private $loginSession;

        public function IsLoggedIn() {
                if($_SESSION[$this->loginSession] == "isLoggedIn") {
                        return true;
                }
                else {
                        return false;
                }
        }

        public function DoLogin($username, $password){

                if ($username != null && $password != null){
                        switch ($username){
                                case "hello";
                                if ($password == "1234"){
                                        $_SESSION[$this->loginSession] == "isLoggedIn";
                                        return true;
                                }
                                else return false;
                                case "hello2";
                                if ($password == "12345"){
                                        $_SESSION[$this->loginSession] == "isLoggedIn";
                                        return true;
                                }
                                else return false;
                        }
                }
                else {
                        return false;
                }
        }

        public function DoLogout(){
                unset($_SESSION[$this->loginSession]);
        }

        public function Test() {

                $this->DoLogout();

                // Test 1: Check so you're not logged in.
                if($this->IsLoggedIn() == true){
                        echo "Test 1 failed";
                        return false;
                }

                // Test 2: Check so that it's not possible to login with wrong password.
                if ($this->DoLogin("hello", "4321") == true){
                        echo "Test 2 failed";
                        return false;
                }

                // Test 3: Check that it's possible to log in.
                if ($this->DoLogin("hello", "1234") == false){
                        echo "Test 3 failed";
                        return false;
                }

                // Test 4: Check that you're logged in
                if ($this->IsLoggedIn() == false){
                        echo "Test 4 failed";
                        return false;
                }

                return true;
        }
}

?>
```

I hope it's enough to include the class and not all the other files, otherwise I'll put them up.

Comment: Where are you calling all of this from? I only see declarations here...please provide more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I see it :-)

$_SESSION[$this->loginSession] == "isLoggedIn";

== should be =

== compares while = sets

Comment: Ah, great! How could I not see that ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the session. `session_start();`  Place it at the very top of the documents (only one time on a page load) you are using.

Comment: Actually I have tried that as well (put it under '<?php') but it's the same result. :/

Comment: you need it regardless.  I dont see a definition for private $loginSession; set that to a string, like login_seesion.  private $loginSession = 'login_session';  It's basically like you are setting $_SESSION[] = 'isLoggedIn'; Do a print_r($_SESSION); to take a look at what you have in there.

Comment: I agree with @wes, however don't forget to check for an existing session first: if (session_id() == ""){session_start();}

Answer (score 0):

$this->loginSession is never set so it's NULL
$_SESSION[null] is not possible as far as i know

change your code to

```
private $loginSession = 'testing';
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put semicolon in your case instruction `case "hello";`There should be a colon. `case "hello": { ...instructions}`